# Font face can't load

Tags: html, css

I use a fontface from font squirrel but they don't load. is there something in the code that has conflict?

```
@font-face {font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
    src: url('/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
    url('/fonts/chunk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/chunk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/chunk-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}
```

Comment: where is `chunk-webfont.eot` file located

Comment: I have index.html, in the same folder fonts and css.

Comment: so all files in one folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@font-face {font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
    src: url('fonts/chunk-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/chunk-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
    url('fonts/chunk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/chunk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/chunk-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}
```